# Query optimisation postgres

Tags: postgresql-performance, partitioning, index-tuning

I have one partitioned table and I have some performance issues.

Here is DB fiddle with schema and query: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u3YABXJXUyAbkx54M3Fnjf/0

Some comments about explain this select.

I don't understand why Postgres iterate through indexes that cannot have data for each `OR` clause.

Ex for partitioned table *(by site)* `digested_sales_1003` it checks:

```
((site_id = 1004) AND (archive_sequential_id &gt;= 451) AND (archive_sequential_id &lt;= 451))
```

This check is useless because it contains `site_id` from another partition.
[image]

Maybe there is another way to write this select? At the moment it takes a lot of time to run it because there exist many `OR` clauses.

**Update 1**
I added explain for this query:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/19E0RwRsPd18rKE3grYSBdq5TQidrmYa5/view?usp=sharing

**Update 2:**
I was able to optimize this select by using the union:

```
SELECT
    t."product_id" AS "productId",
    round(COALESCE(sum(t.qty), 0), 0) AS "totalItems",
    COALESCE(sum(t.final_amount_with_tax), 0) AS "finalAmountWithTax",
    COALESCE(sum(t.final_amount_without_tax), 0) AS "finalAmountWithoutTax",
    COALESCE(sum(t.final_amount_with_tax) - sum(t.initial_amount_with_tax), 0) AS "amountDiscountWithTax",
    COALESCE(max(t.product_price), 0) AS "productPrice",
    COALESCE(max(t.price), 0) AS "price"
FROM (
SELECT
  "product_id",
  qty,
  final_amount_with_tax,
  final_amount_without_tax,
  initial_amount_with_tax,
  product_price,
  price
FROM
  "digested_sales" AS "Sales"
WHERE
  "site_id" = 1003 
  AND "archive_sequential_id" >= 681 
  AND "archive_sequential_id" <= 682
  AND "receipt_status" IN ('blank', 'opened', 'accounted', 'closed')
  AND "content_type" = 'item'
  
UNION ALL

SELECT
  "product_id",
  qty,
  final_amount_with_tax,
  final_amount_without_tax,
  initial_amount_with_tax,
  product_price,
  price
FROM
  "digested_sales" AS "Sales"
WHERE
  "site_id" = 1004 
  AND "archive_sequential_id" >= 451 
  AND "archive_sequential_id" <= 451
  AND "receipt_status" IN ('blank', 'opened', 'accounted', 'closed')
  AND "content_type" = 'item'
  ...
) t
    GROUP BY
        "product_id"
    ORDER BY
        "totalItems" DESC
LIMIT 10
```

But this requires a lot of modifications in codebase.
Perhaps anyone else can give another solution without such drastic changes.

**Update 3:**

I tried to create custom statistic but no result:

```
CREATE STATISTICS IF NOT EXISTS digested_sales_s1 (mcv) ON archive_sequential_id, site_id
FROM digested_sales;
```

Maybe rewrite somehow the where clause or some configuration for Postgres to use partitions smarter.
Thx!

Comment: Execution plans are better shared as plain text generated using `explain (analyze, bufferst)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name done